# PHP INSERT from HTML forms to MySQL db

Tags: html, webforms

I am teaching myself PHP and SQL in my spare time and I am a bit lost as to what I am doing to write the PHP code and where the PHP is actually going.

I am writing a short example for the purpose of this question to have something of my own to look at versus the examples in books and online.

SQL db:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_account
(
account_id          TIMESTAMP(12)       NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY,
name                INTEGER(6)          NOT NULL,
email               VARCHAR(20)         NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT acct_pk PRIMARY KEY (account_ID)
);
```

HTML form: (from Adobe Muse)

```
<div class="clearfix" id="page"><!-- column -->
   <form class="form-grp clearfix colelem" id="widgetu75" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="scripts/form-u75.php"><!-- none box -->
    <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu86" data-required="true"><!-- none box -->
     <label class="fld-label actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u88-5" for="widgetu86_input"><!-- content --><span class="actAsPara">Name:</span></label>
     <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u89-5"><!-- content --><input class="wrapped-input" type="text" spellcheck="false" id="widgetu86_input" name="custom_U86" tabindex="1"/><label class="wrapped-input fld-prompt" id="widgetu86_prompt" for="widgetu86_input"><span class="actAsPara">Enter Name</span></label></span>
    </div>
    <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu82" data-required="true" data-type="email"><!-- none box -->
     <label class="fld-label actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u85-5" for="widgetu82_input"><!-- content --><span class="actAsPara">Email:</span></label>
     <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u83-5"><!-- content --><input class="wrapped-input" type="text" spellcheck="false" id="widgetu82_input" name="Email" tabindex="2"/><label class="wrapped-input fld-prompt" id="widgetu82_prompt" for="widgetu82_input"><span class="actAsPara">Enter Email</span></label></span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u90-5"><!-- content -->
     <p>Submitting Form...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u80-5"><!-- content -->
     <p>The server encountered an error.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u91-5"><!-- content -->
     <p>Form received.</p>
    </div>
    <input class="submit-btn NoWrap grpelem" id="u81-21" type="submit" value="" tabindex="3"/><!-- state-based BG images -->
   </form>
   <div class="verticalspacer"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="preload_images">
   <img class="preload" src="images/u81-21-r.png" alt=""/>
   <img class="preload" src="images/u81-21-m.png" alt=""/>
   <img class="preload" src="images/u81-21-fs.png" alt=""/>
  </div>
```

Image of form:

[image]

1. Should I write the PHP in with the HTML and change the extension from .html to .php or have the HTML page call a PHP script? I'm not sure where I should put it.
2. What would the proper secure code be for this? I have a basic idea but since I am not a true coder I am sure my PHP code would get trashed on this site. :)

My confusion would probably seem pretty basic to most but when reading books on this it seems I get a bunch of examples but no idea where I should be putting them nor how to apply them to something I am doing personally. I am thinking if I could see a working example of something that I am doing myself it might help me.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you don't need to make changes to the code with the form, only to where the form is submitted to - and yes, you rename it to PHP and put the active stuff into it.   That said, you may want to write the whole thing as PHP in a single file as it will make error-checking and resubmission easier.

The question of proper code is to broad for SU, and is one of opinion.   It also depends on your application requirements and complexity.  The question is really more a "generic programming" question, and not really amenable to SU answer.

Comment: I gave it a 1^ for this since technically it is a partial answer. I did figure this out after banging my head on the keyboard for a few days. A lot of discrepencies between reads. Like $sth / $statement and PDO::PARAM_STR should be in or left out. I would get either a blank page or an actual submission into the db. So atleast now myPHPadmin is showing values.

Answer (score 0):

yes, write your PHP code with HTML and change extension .html to .PHP.
follow bellow tutorials and try to solve quiz so you are more clear with PHP :
https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/DEfaULT.asP

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/index.htm